# Do I need presenter in Clean Architecture?

Tags: microservices, clean-architecture

I'm trying to implement Clean Architecture in a microservice, this service return JSON response. Do i need a presenter to present the response DTO or just send it back to the client

Comment: What do you mean by 'presenter' here? Is it coming from M-V-P(Model-view-Presenter)? Generally, in a clean architecture, we have domain layer which contains business entities/model. Any information from domain should be sent through DTO's to client and not directly in order to have loose coupling. Can you share the tutorial you are referring for implementing clean architecture?

Comment: @PraveenRaghuvanshi I just following the concept in this article by Uncle Bob Martin [Clean Architecture](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)

Comment: So, Presenter is referred to something that is aligned to the client needs. We need to safeguard our entities which holds the actual business logic/rules. For client need, we have presenters/controllers. By using presenter/controller we are bringing loose coupling between client and domain layer, which is the preferred practice.  Any change in data representation will be handled at these layers keeping domain entities intact. I think this is well covered under 'Crossing boundaries' and 'What data crosses the boundaries' in the referred article. Hope it clears your query!

Comment: @PraveenRaghuvanshi so if I want to send JSON response, should I return data from the presenter because in REST api I don't need the view

Comment: Yes. REST API's must interact with presenter/controller only and not directly with domain.

Comment: @PraveenRaghuvanshi um, so I have to create another response model, right? and then return that model from the presenter.

Comment: Yes... thats the preferred way to keep things loosely coupled especially while following clean architecture. For e.g Domain might have a class Employee and its information is displayed on UI/View. One way is to directly return Employee object and other way is to introduce a Response data strcuture which could be EmployeeResponse/EmployeeViewModel. Any change/transformation specific to API response could be done at this level keeping domain intact.

Comment: @PraveenRaghuvanshi oh, I got it, thank you very much :D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Clean Architecture the presenter is the component which converts the response model of a use case interactor into a response object which is most convenient for the view (e.g. it may format float number into strings with correct precision).

In case of an API service the presenter would do the same: conversation between service internal data structures and external data contracts (API).

For simple services the internal and external DTOs might be the same. In this case you could omit the presenter initially and introduce it later when needed.

Comment: In case of a business service (not built especially for UI), isn't any internal/external data conversion by definition considered as a business conversion, meaning all conversions should necessarily have to remain within application boundary? Or is there an example for a non-business conversion that should take place at presentation layer?

Answer (score 8):

This was the difficult part for me to implement a `Controller` and `Presenter` for `REST API` following the exact diagram in the article by Uncle Bob Martin [Clean Architecture](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) because the architecture diagram example was for like a web page, so the architecture was for the replacement of `MVC` or `MVP` patterns.

But in case of a `Microservice` you don't need a `View component` and `View Model`.
And the most important thing is that ***you can not completely separate `Controller` and `Presenter`*** because you need to send a response to the microservice using the same interface you've used to get the input from the microservice to the Controller.

This is why I was really struggling to achieve the complete separation of `Controller` and `Presenter`. In case of `Microservice` or `REST API`, you need to make a `Presenter` to ***depend on*** `Controller`.

To do that, you need to create a `Presenter Interface<I>` ***within*** the `Controller Component` and make the `Controller` depend on the `Presenter Interface<I>`, and implement the `Presenter Interface<I>` in `Presenter Component`.

You can actually find this reference in the book by Robert C. Martin `Clean Architecture`, in Chapter 8 OCP: THE OPEN-CLOSED PRINCIPLE, in ***Figure 8.2***.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question, I have to clarify two points: 
Clean Architecture is a high level design pattern that advocates for a clear separation of concerns. A presenter is a component of the software design pattern Model-View-Presenter.

I guess that DTO comes from a different service, in that case Yes. If you want to implement Clean Architecture, you should not expose that DTO to the client.

Comment: I just following the concept in this article by Uncle Bob Martin [Clean Architecture](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you get a JSON object from your Use Cases layer, then you can send it back directly to the client because this will not break the dependency rule.

Cramming some kind of a presenter into your REST API architecture would be a contrived complexity. An API, as the name suggests, is an interface through which your frontend gets data and presents it to the client. There's no presenting in the API itself.